# After install R v3.4.3 inline help menu does not work

Tags: r

I've installed R version 3.4.3 ("Kite Eating Tree") onto my Ubuntu 16.04 computer. When I run RStudio I can access the help manuals inline with no issue (e.g. if I type ?lm the documentation will come up), however when I run a session of R in the Terminal the inline documentation does not work. I've tried ?lm or help(lm), I've also loaded other R packages and tried to access their help documentation and I receive the same error ( the terminal will freeze and I'll have to press Ctrl-C to exit the command).

I downloaded the tarball to install R, and after compiling it I ran `make install-info` and `make install-pdf`, and these haven't made any difference.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install from source?  Easier / better / more integrated to follow [this README and the premade binaries](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I followed the README and have the same issue. I instead copied the local executable "R" file to /usr/bin (i.e. `sudo cp ./R /usr/bin/R`) and the inline help menu is now working.